# License plate combinations

Tags: combinatorics

This is my solution can anyone tell me if it is correct or should I follow another theorem.
How many license plates can be made using either four digits followed by five uppercase English letters or six uppercase English letters followed by three digits?

> $ (10^4×26^5) + (26^6×10^3)? $

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of having an official answer:

Yes, your answer is correct.